# iPhone/iPad: Universal App and InAppSettingsKit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, inappsettingskit

I have a application which is a universal application. On iPhone, it's a Tab Bar application and on iPad its a Split View app. For settings, I really wanted to include the three most *important* settings in my application, and then launch the Settings Application on demand for minor settings (but Apple screwed us there). So I'm trying to integrate InAppSettingsKit.

Because the application is a universal binary, InAppSettingsKit must be installed in `Shared/`. Otherwise I will get problems with duplicate symbols (or I have to duplicate and rename everything with *_iPhone and *_iPad).

I'm trying to cut-in InAppSettingsKit on the iPhone. Because its a tab view, there is no NavigationController as IASK expects (so a tap does nothing except highlight the row cell). So the library will need some modifications. In addition, when I tested a purely iPad cut-in, IASK would `SIGABRT` because it expected a tool bar (IIRC).

The README only has a link to http://www.inappsettingskit.com, which looks like a lot of programmer related marketing.  There are no Universal App samples, and the two samples provided are very basic (not reflecting the needs of a Tab Bar/Split View app). In addition, I have not found a place to ask questions (github does not appear to have a bulletin board system [1]) and there does not appear to be contact information.

Has anyone successfully used InAppSettingsKit in a Universal App? If so, was sharing the best method, or was duplicating files and renaming the best method. Was it worth the effort to debug and modify someone else's work in a vacuum? If someone have a better recommendation, I would love to hear it.

[1] https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit

Comment: Hi jww, I'm about to have these same questions myself as well now very soon. How did you end up going with this? Thanks for any further input you can share, -- Erik

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's an "Issues" area on the GitHub page where you can ask question, too. We don't give individual advice because we wanna avoid duplicate work for a voluntary project.

I don't see why you should need to modify InAppSettingsKit at all depending on whether it's used in a tab bar or split view controller.

Take a look at the sample project where we integrate IASK into a tab bar, a navigation controller and a modal view controller.

Other than that, I'm afraid, I don't have specific advice how to integrate it into a Universal binary.

Comment: "there's an "Issues" area on the GitHub page where you can ask question" - I'm not ready to make a bug report since I don't know if its my failure or InAppSettingsKit's failure (the iPad SIGABRT is probably IASK's failure to validate, but I want to give the benefit of the doubt).

Comment: "I don't see why you should need to modify InAppSettingsKit at all depending on whether it's used in a tab bar or split view controller." - OK, I see you have not tried the configuration.

Comment: " I'm afraid I don't have specific advice how to integrate it into a Universal binary." - OK, thanks.